# Check binary image data

Tags: php, binaryfiles

I need to find what kind of file user have upload by checking binary data, and I found perfect solution for that, over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312607/php-binary-image-data-checking-the-image-type)

Just to be specific this is the function I'm using:

```
function getImgType($filename) {
    $handle = @fopen($filename, 'r');
    if (!$handle)
        throw new Exception('File Open Error');

    $types = array('jpeg' => "\xFF\xD8\xFF", 'gif' => 'GIF', 'png' => "\x89\x50\x4e\x47\x0d\x0a", 'bmp' => 'BM', 'psd' => '8BPS', 'swf' => 'FWS');
    $bytes = fgets($handle, 8);
    $found = 'other';

    foreach ($types as $type => $header) {
        if (strpos($bytes, $header) === 0) {
            $found = $type;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $found;
}
```

Now my question is, how can I get bits for other file types, like `.zip, .exe, mp3, mp4` etc... if there is some kind of list somewhere out there it would be great, though I would like to extract it myself and learn how all of this really works.

Comment: Have you tried with [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) ? And by the way, why don't you use this function to var_dump $bytes for zip, exe, etc ... ?

Comment: [finfo_file (english version)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Comment: It is only supported in `PHP >= 5.3.0` I wold like to support lover versions as well.

Comment: I would strongly advice not to use older PHP versions, for security reasons

Comment: This may help: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [file magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number).

The magic number *is a type* of file signature - since sometimes it **takes more than the magic number** to identify the file.

A (very) short list of such numbers can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). A larger list can be found [here](http://www.filesignatures.net/).

File identification websites often times also mention the file magic number.

In linux, the [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command can be used to identify files.
In PHP you can use the [FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) set of functions to identify files.

---

By the way, you did not specify the kind of files you want to identify. Sometimes, identification might be the wrong solution. For example, people used to want to identify files before passing them to GD or saving them on the server as images.
In this case, identification is not really your job. Instead, use the following code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('data.dat'); // File might eventcontain a JPG...it is
                                       // still loaded without problems!
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data); // ... since this function just needs the
                                       // file's data, nothing more.
```

Comment: Well, it's always a race to the best answer, isn't it? :)

Comment: So if i understood it correctly `mp3` magic number would be `49 44 33`?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that not every file that starts with `49 44 33` is an actual MP3 file.

Comment: Hmm with my function that i use right now it doesn't find those number, instead it finds `ID3`, it's a little confusing

Comment: Oh, it's `\x49\x44\x33`. Those are the bytes, represented in hexadecimal, equivalent to `ID3` in ASCII.

Comment: Oh now this makes sense, so last question, is there a difference if i use hex or ASCII?

Comment: @Linas Hex, decimal, octal etc are all number systems. They are interchangeable. For example, "20" in hex is "32" in decimal. ASCII on the other hand, is a character set, that is, a byte of decimal value 32 is a space character in ASCII.

Comment: [ID3 is the name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) of the meta data record of MP3 files. It contains meta information about the file, like title, album, genre. So ID3 may actually be the header of an ID3 record. It could be that maybe not all MP3 files have an ID3 record, and it could also be that other (music) file do have an ID3 record, even though they're not MP3 files.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called "*File Signatures*", "*Magic Bytes*", or "*Magic Numbers*".

[**This page**](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) lists a lot of them for many file formats

However, I wouldn't rely on them for identifying file formats. **Use [PHP's finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)** instead.

Answer (score 2):

Most files have a specific *header* or *file signature* or (apparently) *magic number*, which are different names for the same thing: a fixed set of bytes at the start of the file.

For instance, [.exe starts with 'MZ'](http://www.fileformat.info/format/exe/corion-mz.htm), [.zip has a fixed 4 byte sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#File_headers)

This webpage contains a lot of file signatures:
http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

If you search for `.extension file format` or `.extension file header`, you will usually find a description of the file format.