# byte[] image is not renderer correctly by HttpServlet

Tags: image, servlets, byte

I've got this piece of coding which, when displayed in Firefox or Chrome, throws an exception (the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors).

```
            byte[] img2 = { 105, 86, 66, 79, 82, 119, 48, 75, 71, 103, 111, 65, 65, 65, 65, 78, 83, 85, 104, 69, 85, 103,
            65, 65, 65, 68, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 101, 67, 65, 89, 65, 65, 65, 66, 113, 112, 74, 51, 66, 65, 65, 65,
            65, 71, 88, 82, 70, 87, 72, 82, 84, 98, 50, 90, 48, 100, 50, 70, 121, 90, 81, 66, 66, 90, 71, 57, 105,
            90, 83, 66, 74, 98, 87, 70, 110, 90, 86, 74, 108, 89, 87, 82, 53, 99, 99, 108, 108, 80, 65, 65, 65, 65,
            50, 112, 74, 82, 69, 70, 85, 101, 78, 114, 115, 87, 69, 49, 73, 86, 71, 69, 85, 118, 102, 54, 107, 111,
            87, 108, 69, 97, 101, 85, 89, 113, 73, 115, 89, 85, 55, 82, 78, 106, 107, 81, 104, 87, 81, 109, 90,
            103, 90, 67, 103, 76, 105, 113, 85, 119, 69, 88, 89, 72, 119, 81, 117, 99, 117, 85, 109, 107, 66, 90,
            87, 71, 122, 99, 87, 69, 112, 82, 85, 71, 66, 81, 73, 47, 85, 99, 82, 97, 89, 69, 74, 97, 111, 71, 107,
            107, 87, 78, 81, 75, 108, 79, 97, 83, 85, 111, 47, 99, 57, 53, 52, 72, 47, 102, 55, 51, 110, 115, 122,
            85, 113, 115, 72, 99, 43, 69, 78, 56, 55, 53, 53, 99, 57, 56, 57, 53, 53, 53, 55, 118, 106, 99, 84,
            107, 49, 86, 53, 113, 88, 57, 76, 57, 114, 113, 116, 113, 99, 109, 74, 53, 75, 97, 89, 109, 102, 116,
            74, 119, 50, 78, 84, 98, 54, 106, 56, 49, 80, 85, 47, 98, 103, 51, 85, 72, 117, 115, 50, 53, 109, 87,
            103, 57, 108, 104, 121, 101, 85, 81, 66, 82, 65, 72, 56, 90, 56, 84, 106, 53, 102, 102, 67, 78, 49,
            111, 77, 68, 78, 107, 106, 84, 69, 105, 108, 70, 87, 118, 121, 76, 101, 116, 66, 67, 122, 79, 115, 106,
            67, 78, 111, 120, 101, 84, 47, 77, 109, 116, 90, 107, 121, 97, 66, 122, 43, 55, 49, 106, 116, 72, 69,
            53, 75, 121, 53, 53, 107, 108, 76, 111, 84, 74, 102, 78, 117, 108, 109, 115, 109, 83, 84, 121, 115, 65,
            105, 110, 121, 48, 65, 120, 75, 43, 53, 99, 90, 111, 102, 55, 54, 70, 53, 102, 52, 47, 108, 111, 114,
            81, 57, 51, 90, 83, 52, 102, 114, 117, 83, 102, 80, 47, 112, 76, 105, 88, 53, 115, 47, 90, 68, 49, 78,
            76, 120, 110, 70, 52, 79, 84, 112, 106, 114, 65, 49, 101, 80, 109, 116, 101, 51, 100, 98, 50, 105, 106,
            106, 115, 68, 116, 105, 84, 100, 101, 117, 121, 104, 97, 121, 50, 86, 121, 108, 112, 116, 56, 50, 48,
            70, 65, 71, 75, 115, 43, 53, 105, 57, 104, 71, 73, 84, 86, 108, 78, 83, 84, 106, 87, 116, 76, 98, 108,
            67, 71, 121, 116, 102, 85, 50, 66, 86, 117, 88, 75, 82, 68, 117, 114, 109, 111, 51, 102, 75, 79, 84,
            79, 111, 77, 56, 97, 115, 78, 112, 122, 114, 99, 83, 119, 101, 85, 90, 122, 118, 85, 99, 55, 82, 74,
            98, 49, 52, 55, 110, 114, 69, 71, 89, 104, 76, 51, 107, 82, 120, 66, 97, 49, 48, 47, 79, 107, 82, 43,
            114, 54, 52, 48, 108, 104, 98, 68, 65, 120, 113, 106, 75, 107, 65, 84, 108, 81, 88, 109, 85, 120, 76,
            43, 84, 66, 89, 50, 82, 87, 65, 113, 106, 57, 81, 83, 67, 100, 114, 105, 113, 105, 113, 49, 71, 117,
            99, 81, 48, 89, 121, 76, 116, 43, 49, 66, 50, 115, 72, 73, 78, 55, 117, 81, 116, 122, 56, 47, 89, 47,
            78, 81, 82, 67, 72, 54, 85, 74, 74, 74, 57, 72, 110, 70, 48, 111, 83, 109, 81, 106, 115, 90, 97, 97,
            110, 75, 69, 86, 75, 65, 70, 76, 118, 105, 79, 98, 54, 72, 85, 98, 104, 72, 75, 50, 78, 75, 110, 68,
            77, 107, 90, 54, 76, 111, 51, 100, 111, 81, 118, 108, 117, 87, 66, 99, 113, 122, 115, 43, 103, 107, 97,
            56, 98, 68, 66, 68, 111, 66, 72, 100, 66, 90, 43, 102, 103, 76, 113, 57, 53, 89, 120, 107, 54, 113,
            120, 121, 89, 69, 49, 50, 67, 99, 111, 68, 98, 117, 118, 113, 85, 100, 83, 109, 118, 90, 85, 109, 73,
            119, 53, 99, 88, 43, 105, 74, 65, 100, 65, 121, 88, 109, 67, 52, 70, 102, 88, 75, 65, 101, 87, 90, 69,
            90, 53, 111, 55, 52, 77, 118, 76, 115, 76, 106, 76, 109, 89, 115, 80, 97, 87, 100, 68, 112, 52, 86,
            112, 100, 105, 107, 53, 87, 47, 56, 77, 111, 77, 121, 88, 89, 55, 54, 47, 77, 101, 75, 106, 106, 51,
            54, 47, 119, 90, 120, 115, 100, 49, 86, 112, 114, 118, 110, 101, 83, 85, 73, 111, 111, 76, 86, 120,
            116, 121, 85, 47, 79, 103, 97, 110, 107, 100, 51, 81, 56, 57, 100, 86, 70, 70, 74, 117, 108, 109, 113,
            100, 43, 110, 48, 99, 65, 89, 66, 100, 72, 66, 122, 110, 110, 51, 106, 111, 102, 116, 43, 111, 114, 88,
            120, 67, 66, 99, 51, 89, 79, 108, 65, 73, 113, 78, 101, 119, 83, 100, 49, 116, 87, 70, 74, 99, 116, 74,
            81, 110, 55, 103, 48, 83, 73, 71, 86, 49, 68, 106, 53, 70, 72, 109, 73, 53, 111, 77, 122, 81, 103, 47,
            55, 112, 52, 79, 117, 48, 85, 112, 81, 69, 75, 71, 102, 65, 98, 115, 78, 66, 76, 104, 121, 81, 67, 67,
            84, 69, 82, 102, 79, 71, 78, 84, 79, 51, 89, 74, 107, 106, 100, 77, 106, 113, 82, 74, 80, 76, 102, 53,
            84, 89, 87, 53, 84, 106, 43, 74, 108, 107, 51, 48, 107, 43, 87, 74, 101, 83, 89, 70, 49, 76, 52, 69,
            55, 87, 121, 87, 54, 107, 53, 57, 98, 110, 73, 69, 73, 72, 77, 104, 122, 108, 74, 101, 87, 103, 77, 56,
            102, 121, 119, 101, 54, 76, 65, 112, 106, 57, 107, 65, 109, 77, 87, 106, 97, 56, 122, 80, 82, 85, 82,
            43, 117, 48, 109, 120, 48, 99, 84, 69, 74, 56, 112, 66, 56, 77, 89, 70, 78, 72, 122, 82, 115, 88, 104,
            43, 53, 65, 55, 68, 122, 56, 80, 84, 115, 109, 53, 98, 52, 103, 114, 82, 79, 66, 84, 85, 54, 54, 70,
            47, 74, 103, 86, 117, 81, 53, 65, 52, 106, 52, 78, 75, 111, 80, 72, 107, 66, 66, 66, 117, 71, 99, 65,
            89, 122, 113, 79, 55, 78, 100, 70, 57, 117, 98, 121, 111, 49, 99, 48, 106, 113, 82, 118, 54, 54, 105,
            119, 79, 119, 97, 68, 117, 122, 99, 77, 116, 53, 43, 109, 70, 113, 101, 104, 69, 74, 115, 98, 119, 118,
            79, 81, 114, 97, 106, 119, 122, 67, 76, 115, 108, 104, 109, 66, 119, 57, 122, 89, 69, 115, 54, 82, 48,
            112, 83, 119, 112, 75, 55, 101, 69, 121, 81, 55, 85, 51, 55, 119, 117, 90, 72, 121, 73, 99, 57, 53,
            102, 79, 97, 115, 57, 50, 117, 47, 86, 71, 80, 50, 113, 79, 47, 121, 75, 73, 65, 111, 103, 68, 99, 68,
            105, 67, 99, 86, 55, 115, 104, 89, 116, 122, 43, 53, 43, 53, 102, 65, 81, 89, 65, 80, 115, 81, 106,
            121, 52, 54, 108, 99, 104, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 83, 85, 86, 79, 82, 75, 53, 67, 89, 73, 73, 61 };

    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setContentLength(img2.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(img2, 0, img2.length);
    response.getOutputStream().close();
```

If I embed the same piece in an HTML it all works okay.
Can anybody tell me why?

```
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the byte array is a JPEG, it should start with a standard JPEG signature, but yours doesn't.  It's hard to tell what's going on since you didn't provide any information about where these bytes came from, but what you should be looking for is something like this:

255 216 255 224   0  16  74  70  73  70

for the first 9 bytes -- the last 4 of those spell "JFIF"

This can vary, but the first two bytes should definitely be FFC0 - start of image

What's a mystery is why the base64-encoded image displays correctly.

Oh I see now: it's a PNG not a JPEG.  Check this answer: [PHP : binary image data, checking the image type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312607/php-binary-image-data-checking-the-image-type) it should help.

There also seems to be something wrong with your conversion since the first bytes of your array are not the same as the first bytes of the base64 png (those are: 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, or in decimal: 137, 80, 78)

Comment: The first bytes of the array [105 86 66 79 82 119 48,...] translate to  i V B O R w 0 (ASCII) which is exactly what's in the BASE64 string. This image is a PNG but when I embed it in the page with the statement  `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64 `I can put anything in the image type (jpeg, png, yyy) it always renders correctly. The problem is with the Java Servlet. So the array of bytes, which comes from a fileuploader control, is correct (and in fact when I convert it to BASE64 it displays perfectly) but don't know why it doesn't render in a servlet.

Comment: I think you are laboring under a misapprehension: namely that 1 byte of base64 translates directly to one byte of binary, but this  is not true.  Basically every 4 bytes of base64 == 3 bytes of binary.  See what I said in my original answer about the byte values you should be seeing.  This has nothing to do with servlets.