# Determine filetype without extension in silverlight c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Im developing a webapp where the user can upload an image to the server.
I want to ensure that the user uploads an image, and not anything else, like a reverse shell or something malicious. Therefore I cannot use the extensions since you can easily fake that.

```
 var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            //dlg.Filter = "";
            dlg.Multiselect = false;

            bool? openClicked = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (openClicked == true)
            {
                Stream stream = dlg.File.OpenRead();

                BinaryReader binary = new BinaryReader(stream);

//Determine filetype here.

                byte[] data = binary.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);
```

There must be a simple way to do this?

Tl;dr: How do I determine filetype to prevent a reverse shell?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312607/php-binary-image-data-checking-the-image-type) you can just check the bits at the start of the stream

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply file filters like this,

```
     OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
     dlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|PNG Images (*.png)|*.png";
```

Comment: "Therefore I cannot use the extensions since you can easily fake that."  The questioner is well aware that file extensions are not sufficient, however it seems that you are not.