# Type of image stored as image datatype

Tags: sql-server, image

There's an application that stores some icons in the database with the data type as image.  I'm having a very difficult time figuring out what type of file is being stored so that I can export it as an actual image/icon.

Question 1: Is there any way to find out the type of image stored in sql server under the image data type?

Question 2: They populate this table from a text file.  Here's what's in it (sorry if this is spammy, but maybe it's recognizable to some).  I'm trying to figure out the type of image it is:

```
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
```

In response to "What is stored in the database, example please"
In sql server, with datatype image, this is the value stored (same as above, but with 0x in front):

```
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
```

Comment: what is stored in the database (example, plz)?

Comment: edited with exact value stored as image data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a similar post: [PHP : binary image data, checking the image type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312607/php-binary-image-data-checking-the-image-type)

As for what you can do from a SQL side is nothing, the application extracting the data will need to figure it out.  This is what BOL has to say about it:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189574(v=sql.105).aspx

```
Data in an image data is stored as a string of bits and is not interpreted by SQL Server. 
Any interpretation of the data in an image column must be made by the application. For 
example, an application could store data in an image column using a BMP, TIFF, GIF, or 
JPEG format. The application that reads the data from the image column must recognize the 
format of the data and display it correctly. All an image column does is provide a 
location to store the stream of bits that make up the image data value.
```

Comment: and expanding on that, this format does not appear to be any common image type... so you have your work cut out for you.

Comment: That said, it appears to be a simple bitmap format with a header for the first.... probably 80 bytes.

Comment: oh joy :) - thanks for the help pseudonym.  I'll start working it out.

Comment: @user3071296 did you found any solution for this? if yes plz share it with me.