# How to check a blob file is a image in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm using Laravel `5.3`,
I crop a image with javascript and upload it with ajax.
The cropped image is changed to a blob file when uploading.

But in backend,How to check the  blob file is a image?

```
public function changeAvatar(Request $request)
{
    $user = \Auth::user();
    $blob = $request->croppedImage;
    $destinationPath = 'images/uploads/';
    $fileName = $user->id . '_' . time() . '.png';
    $file = file_put_contents($destinationPath.$fileName, $blob);


     $input = array('image' => $file);
     $rules = array(
         'image' => 'image'
     );
     $validator = \Validator::make($input, $rules);
     if ( $validator->fails() ) {
         return \Response::json([
             'success' => false,
             'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
         ]);

     }

    $user ->avatar = '/'.$destinationPath.$fileName;
    $user ->save();

    return \Response::json([
        'success'=>true,
        'avatar'=>asset($destinationPath.$fileName),
    ]);
}
```

the file is a image,but the error is always like this:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"image":["image must be an image."]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if this work:

After you write the blob into the destination path, do this:

```
//...
$file = file_put_contents($destinationPath.$fileName, $blob);

$uploadedFile = new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile($file, "dummy");

$input = array('image' => $uploadedFile);
//...
```

Laravel's image validation requires the file to be an instance of UploadedFile to be able to pass the validation.

Comment: ErrorException in UploadedFile.php line 88:
Missing argument 2 for Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::__construct(), called in D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-dev\app\Http\Controllers\UsersController.php on line 28 and defined

Comment: I'm sorry. Argument two is "originalName". Supply a dummy string should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could test the contents of the blob, using a first-bits test.

This way, there is no need to first upload the file to the filesystem, and removing later.

It's explained here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312996)