# Get the file extension of a base64 encoded string

Tags: php, base64, file-extension

How can you get the file extension of a *base64* encoded string in PHP?

In my case, this file happens to be an *image*:

```
$base64_encoded_string = $_POST['image_base64_string'];

$extension = ??
```

How can I get the file extension from `$base64_encoded_string` ?

> **EDIT:** This is NOT part of an upload form so `$_FILES` data cannot be used here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a one-liner inspired by **@msg's** answer:

```
$extension = explode('/', mime_content_type($base64_encoded_string))[1];
```

Comment: `mime_content_type` expects a filename so this has me confused

Comment: Apparently, _base64_ data is treated like a file name according to the result I got from my code.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: but... an extnsion behind this code 'data:image/png;base64' is unreliable , right? @Mystical

Comment: Here you can find a way to get something like "application/pdf"  
But you have to use decode first to get the binary and then use finfo and buffer:


$file_content = base64_decode($base64EncodedString, true);       
$finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimeType = $finfo->buffer($file_content);


I got it from this response:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312607/php-binary-image-data-checking-the-image-type

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
function getBytesFromHexString($hexdata)
{
  for($count = 0; $count < strlen($hexdata); $count+=2)
    $bytes[] = chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $count, 2)));

  return implode($bytes);
}

function getImageMimeType($imagedata)
{
  $imagemimetypes = array( 
    "jpeg" => "FFD8", 
    "png" => "89504E470D0A1A0A", 
    "gif" => "474946",
    "bmp" => "424D", 
    "tiff" => "4949",
    "tiff" => "4D4D"
  );

  foreach ($imagemimetypes as $mime => $hexbytes)
  {
    $bytes = getBytesFromHexString($hexbytes);
    if (substr($imagedata, 0, strlen($bytes)) == $bytes)
      return $mime;
  }

  return NULL;
}

$encoded_string = "....";
$imgdata = base64_decode($encoded_string);
$mimetype = getImageMimeType($imgdata);
```

Source: https://newbedev.com/detecting-image-type-from-base64-string-in-php

Answer (score 2):

If this is part of a upload form, you can get the information about the files from the [$_FILES variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

If it's a raw field you can decode it and run it through [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) or equivalent and take a guess.

If you are open to using libraries, you can look into [mimey](https://github.com/ralouphie/mimey) or [php-mimetyper](https://github.com/adrienrn/php-mimetyper).

Comment: It is not part of an upload form, though.

Comment: Right, except you don't decode it, you run it through `mime_content_type` raw.

Answer (score 2):

```
//This function return the extension from mimetype
function getImageMimeType(string $encodedImage)
{
    $decodedImage = base64_decode($encodedImage);
    return (explode('/', finfo_buffer(finfo_open(), $decodedImage, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE))[1]);
}
    
$encodedImage = '        ';
$extension = getImageMimeType($encodedImage);
echo $extension;
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex can extract the image type from the base64 header :

```
                  ┌───┐
$b64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII";
preg_match("/\/(.*?);/", $b64, $MATCH);
              ↑     ↑
              └─────┘  RETURNS STRING BETWEEN / AND ;
echo $MATCH[1];
```

It should display `png`.

Notice the slash must be escaped `\/`, while semicolon does not require it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I tried to upload a CSV file all examples returned the `plain/text` mime type, which technically is true but wrong when we try to find a file extension.

I ended up with the following solution (some Symfony code presented):

```php
$base64Uri = "data:text/csv;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF.......";
preg_match('/^data:(.*);base64/', $base64Uri, $match);
$mimeType = $match[1];
$extension = \Symfony\Component\Mime\MimeTypes::getDefault()->getExtensions($mimeType)[0];
```